# How to get json array in controller js in ionic 1?

Tags: javascript, php, json

My server response like

```
{"items": [{"item_id":"1","item_name":"Skirt"},
           {"item_id":"2","item_name":"Track"}]}
```

I need like

```
items: [
            {
                item_id: 1,
                item_name: 'Skirt'
            },
        {
            item_id: 2,
            item_name: 'Track'
        }
    ]
```

Please help.

Comment: i don't see any explanation of what you want achieve

Comment: use JSON.parse(server_response);

Answer (score 0):

Store json response into one variable

then

```
<?php
   $jsonresponse=json_decode($json);
   print_r($jsonresponse)
?>
```

Comment: first you convert json to array

Comment: The josn response itself  a array.Sir if you need the code then i can send you in your mail,because i have face this problem in every projects....Please help

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()`

```js
data ='{"items": [{"item_id":"1","item_name":"Skirt"},{"item_id":"2","item_name":"Track"}]}';

data = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(data);
```